# #1242: Subquery Returns more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1242

I have a problem regarding mysql.

I have few tables like `course`, `papers`, `students`, `studentspapers`

Now what I want is that my query should return the result like:

It should select student name, student category from students table, students optional paper from studentspaper but I have not mentioned anything in my studentpapers table but in papers table.

Papers table have id as primary key which I have used in studentspaper as foreign key.

Now the simple query I am using is:

```
select
  st.name,
  s.paperid
from
  students st,
  sps s join papers
  on paperid
where
  paperid = (select p.p_id from papers p where type='optional')
  and st.course=1
```

I dont know what shall I do.

Its saying subquery return more than 1 row #1242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is:

```
select st.name, s.paperid
from students st,
     sps s join
     papers
     on paperid
where paperid= (select p.p_id from papers p where type='optional') and st.course=1
```

It is missing a join between students and sps.  I think you mean:

```
select st.name, s.paperid
from students st join
     sps s
     on st.studentid = sps.studentid join
     papers p
     on p.paperid = sps.paperid
where p.type='optional' and st.course=1
```

However, without seeing the structure of the tables, it is hard to say if this is the right query.

Comment: Thank you so much. Seriously you made my day.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you have to change your SQL to sth this:

```
select st.name, s.paperid 
from students st, sps s join papers on paperid 
where paperid in (select p.p_id from papers p where type='optional') and st.course=1
```

I just changed the "=" to the "in".

This should resolve your problem.

Comment: This link should be here: [MySQL Comparison Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Comment: This answer is correct. If this answer helped you, please, accept it.

Comment: I guess my question wasn't proper. What i want is that from studentpaper table it should take out those paper whose id equals the id of the paper table where type=optional.

Comment: @iperfect OK, try using "not in" instead of "in". This way you will exclude all the paperid that has the type=optional.